# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) ../opencv_contrib/modules/dnn_superres/src/dnn_superres.cpp:97: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Model not specified

Tags: opencv, dnn9

## Im trying out this article;

https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-based-super-resolution-with-opencv-4fd736678066

*this is the code copied out of the article;*

import cv2
from cv2 import dnn_superres

sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()

image = cv2.imread('./input.png')

path = "EDSR_x3.pb"
sr.readModel(path)

sr.setModel("edsr", 3)

result = sr.upsample(image)

cv2.imwrite("./upscaled.png", result)

## i also tried opencv Super Resolution Tutorial;

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d29/tutorial_dnn_superres_upscale_image_single.html

import cv2
from cv2 import dnn_superres

sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()

image = cv2.imread('./image.png')

path = "EDSR_x4.pb"
sr.readModel(path)

sr.setModel("edsr", 4)

result = sr.upsample(image)

cv2.imwrite("./upscaled.png", result)

*My enviroment is anaconda3 opencv 4.3.0.
I either get the error from the title or i get "killed" when i run the opencv example*.

*My file directory is all on the same level of the sample codes. I would just change my image file names.
I did try to compile opencv and opencv_contrib from cmake but, i didn't know how to have python refer to opencv and opencv_contrib from source.
ifollow this documentation to install opencv from source;
https://d*ocs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html

*I opted to use anaconda wrapping of opencv 4.3.0 because i ran into too many dependency and wrongly installed package problems.*

My friend from a meetup managed to apply the code from the article just as the article depicted while i tried to follow exactly what he did, using an anaconda enviorment. Would my problem stem from my virtual enviorment or opencv package version or the code itself? i did have another colleague run my code from my github branch and he had my exact same problems. How should i apprach the bugs im having and apply the super resolution examples i found?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error 'Model not specified' comes from the fact that the Net is empty. You have to actually download [the model](https://github.com/Saafke/EDSR_Tensorflow/tree/master/models) and then provide the path to the 'sr.readModel()' function.

If you did that and it still does not work, you could try these two things:

1. Try a smaller image (in .png format).
2. Build OpenCV from [source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv). Do not forget the [contrib modules](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) (this is where the dnn_superres module resides). You said you had a problem linking python. I would suggest to use [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html). After following that tutorial, do the following command (after you already did `sudo make install`), to link the python libraries:

`sudo ldconfig`